# count occurence numbre of ip address C#

Tags: c#

I have text file that contains for generating data type one of them is ip address i make regular expression filter only ip@ and i would like to count occurance of each ip@ i make code but don't working for me i need your help

```
 public static int annabacount(string ipfind) {

        int anCount = 0;
        string ipf = ipfind;
        anCount = Regex.Matches(ipf,".123").Count;

        return annabacount(ipfind);
    } 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("D:\\0000.txt");
        string ip="";
        Regex ipr = new Regex(@"172\.29\.1(23|36|24|41)\.[0-255]{3}\:2944");



        while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
            ip = sr.ReadLine();

            Match match = ipr.Match(ip);
            annabacount(match.ToString());                                                                         

            Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(annabacount(match.ToString()));
```

Comment: The dash character indicating at range only works for a single character : [0-255]

Comment: Regex is for syntactic check. Semantic things like value  cam be only hacked. Look here: https://regular-expressions.mobi/ip.html?wlr=1

Comment: yes and i repeat this character 3 times with {3}

Comment: ZorgoZ so i can't use regex for counting ?

Comment: i want to count ip for each number of the 3rd octet 123/136/141/124

Comment: this doesn't do what you think it does `[0-255]{3}` you need something like this: `\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

Comment: i have the result of ip address but the count dosn't work